# After I added made a custom cursor using html,css and js, that cursor is not working on links or button .How should I solve it?

Tags: javascript, html, css

```
const cursor = document.querySelector('.cursor');

document.addEventListener('mousemove', e => {
  cursor.setAttribute("style","top: "+(e.pageY-10)+"px; left: "+(e.pageX-10)+"px;")
})

document.addEventListener('click' ,() => {
  cursor.classList.add("expand"); 

  setTimeout(() =>{
    cursor.classList.remove("expand");
  }, 500);
})
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Add the style `pointer-events: none;` to your custom cursor to stop your cursor responding to mouse events such as click (or touch).

See working example below:

```js
const cursor = document.querySelector('.cursor');

document.addEventListener('mousemove', e => {
  cursor.setAttribute("style","top: "+(e.pageY-10)+"px; left: "+(e.pageX-10)+"px;") 
})

document.addEventListener('click' ,() => {
    cursor.classList.add("expand"); 

    setTimeout(() =>{
    cursor.classList.remove("expand");
  }, 500)
})
```

```css
* {
  cursor: none;
}
.cursor {
  height: 20px;
  width: 20px;
  background: black;
  border-radius: 100px;
  position: absolute;
  pointer-events: none; /* add pointer-events: none */
}
```

```html
<div class="cursor"></div>
<a href="https://www.example.com">Link</a>
```

Alternatively, instead of hiding the cursor and using a div to replace it, you can give it a custom image using:

```
* {
  cursor: url('https://i.stack.imgur.com/8ka1W.png'), auto;
}
```

See example below:

```css
* {
  cursor: url('https://i.stack.imgur.com/8ka1W.png'), auto;
}
```

```html
<a href="https://www.example.com">Link</a>
```

Answer (score 0):

Try adding the following CSS:

```
.cursor {
  position: absolute;
}
```

Here's a fiddle: https://jsfiddle.net/bsxj7pyg/

An element with `position: absolute;` is positioned relative to the nearest positioned ancestor. In this case, it would follow the cursor.